# vsHost.exe, Ruining my speed, continues to run after exiting Visual Studio

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep

Wanted: any tips or tricks to relieve the CPU usage which is causing my app (and as a result, my entire system) to slow to a crawl.

I have an app. It invokes several threads. Probably about 5 (guessing at the moment). The Serial Port thread is an absolute gotta. I'm reasonably confident that that thread is acting responsibly (e.g., all the bytes get there, like they're supposed to be).

I have a couple of other threads that watch the results of the background serial port handler, and respond to semaphores that happen in things like `button1_click` routines and so on so that everybody gets along and the whole thing runs smoothly. Basically, they are just big while loops that check semaphores and branch if the values say so.

I recently added twenty additional individual threads; separate from the others. These threads put dots and lines on 20 rectangles (the device in question has 20 channels). My app exists to record and graph them.

The App got real slow, immediately, as the result of adding those threads. In fact, the entire machine got real slow.

So I stopped the app; and the machine was still slow. So I exited Visual Studio; still slow.

Secondary symptom: a fan in the computer itself increased its speed; then increased its speed again; and maybe a third time. I think it was the power supply fan; but whatever, it was a fan and it continued to increase its speed.
Task manager showed me this...

[image: Task Manager Performance]
The Processes tab revealed that the big hog was...

> myApp.vshost.exe

his "Description" of that process was...

> vshost32.exe

I used the task manager to end the process.

By the way, this was not an application, there was no such named app listed on the `Applications` tab. I saw it in the `Processes` tab only.

After ending the `myApp.vshost32.exe` process, CPU usage dropped back, like right in harmony, like this...

[image: Task Manager After Ending vshost32.exe]
The nearly vertical increases in CPU Usage were all highly correlated with the act of starting the twenty new threads. (A button click starts the threads; one click, zap, CPU 100.) The drop back to near-zero correlated perfectly with the act of ending `vshost32.exe` so I'm highly confident (at this moment, at least) that `vshost32.exe` was responsible.

The problem started when I added this section...

```
       //
       //
       //  Do a bunch of stuff to set up the 20 graphs; had no problem
       // 
       // 

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {                                   // Start each thread
             our20Graphs[i].Begin();        // Start my problems
        }                                   // Entire machine now goes 2 MPH
```

The actual culprit, in its own class, in its own file, is here...

```
    this.th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunTarget));

    //
    //
    // lots of other stuff
    //
    //
    //

    public void Begin()                             ///// A method in the Runtarget 
    {
        this.th.Start();
        this.th.IsBackground = true;
    }
```

I have seen other apps, similar to my task, which create a highly similar set of graphs, actively, in real time, without anywhere near these extremes of CPU usage, and way faster.

At the present time, my graphing routines are taking so much time that the data simply does not ever appear on the screen. No clue what's going on with all that.

If that wasn't bad enough (and it's worse than bad enough, it's the show stopper) this is slowing the entire machine down to the point that my app is worse than a prima donna app, it's totally disqualified from any usage at all (the machine essentially stops cold).

So then, why do 20 threads overtax the system so hideously ?

Am I supposed to purposely put each thread to sleep for a little while so that the other threads will get a chance to do their stuff ?

Biggest Quandary of all: why did `myApp.vshost.exe` keep on running (as a 99% CPU hog) even after I had ended the app and exited Visual Studio ?

Suggestions are welcome on what I might do to eliminate whatever it is that is hogging so much CPU time.

(Added Edit, on community advice, this is RunTarget)

```
    private void RunTarget()
    {
        while (proceed)
        {
            if (!finished)
            {
                if (!pause)
                {
                    this.screenReady = false;
                    g.Clear(Color.Black);

                    //   bg.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Aqua, 3), new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 40));
                    //  oldG.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3), new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 40));

                    if (v_surface)
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(beginSurface, new Point(ImagePlace - area.Width, 0));

                        g.DrawImage(OldSurface, new Point(ImagePlace + 1, 0));

                        // g.DrawString(ArrayPlacement.ToString(),new Font("Arial",18),Brushes.Blue,new PointF(20,20));
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        g.DrawImage(OldSurface, new Point(ImagePlace - area.Width, 0));

                        g.DrawImage(beginSurface, new Point(ImagePlace + 1, 0));

                    }

                    this.screenReady = true;

                    if (ImagePlace % 64 == 0)               //// 64 is the size of the array of ints
                    {
                        finished = true;
                    }

                    if (ImagePlace == area.Width)
                    {
                        ImagePlace = 0;

                        if (v_surface)
                        {
                            v_surface = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            v_surface = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImagePlace += 32;               //// This is the scrolling increment
                    }

                    Draw();                             //// This physically puts it on the screen
                }
            }
        }
    }                                                   //// End of private void RunTarget()
```

Comment: Thread schedule thrashing? 25 active threads on 4 cores seems a little excessive.

Comment: You seem to have shown us just about everything *except* the one thing that might reveal the issue - the code in `RunTarget` that these 20 threads are actually running.

Comment: @asawyer I have seen a similar app do exactly that: 20 threads drawing 20 channels of data, in real time, without any noticeable impact on the system, and without any noticeable delay. Speed was 256 Hz, just like mine. I am highly confident that this can be done, as I've seen it. The only difference was that he had a random generator of fake numbers while I'm getting real numbers from the serial port.

Comment: @Iridium okay, I will search for that now. Do I edit my original message ? Put in a new "answer" here ? (with RunTarget, whatever). Sorry for my ineptitude. Really want to give you what you need to answer this.

Comment: @User.1 Just edit in the additional information.

Comment: @asawyer okay found it. It's 61 lines long. Will that be okay ?

Comment: @User.1, did you try disabling VS hosting process?

Comment: @Dhawalk No. Educate me.

Comment: @User.1, check the answer below.

Comment: @Dhawalk examining that now, thanks, will let you know.  Just found it, thanks for the clear and accurate menu crawl-down path. Trying it now. If I'm gone for half an hour, it means that the thing is still bogging me down.

Comment: Where does your RunTarget code yield to wait for results?  Either it needs to wait for some signal (yielding back to the CPU) or it needs to poll (Thread.Sleep being a typical way of doing this.)  Without some sort of yielding, your thread will greedily consume as much CPU as the system can give it.

Comment: You will still have to close the VS session once to kill the existing vshost process

Comment: Is the serial port pushing data fast enough that you require 20 separate threads doing full bore rendering? How about a nice push based setup with Observable<T> library so that the screen updates only when new data is pushed into the port?

Comment: @DanBryant I think you have hit something significant. Can you suggest a sleeping schedule ?  I have data coming at me in chunks of 4096 bytes at a time, I think that happens in 0.250 seconds (I'll check if it's important) and I believe that I get 64 individual samples during that quarter second. I'll give you more specific details if you need.

Comment: @Dhawalk I'll try your idea first before writing code

Comment: @Dhawalk Just did that. Now I can't connect to the serial port. Will see if putting it back restores my ability to connect. Ooops, whole system is now confused. Gotta Restart

Comment: It may be related to trust. please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @DanBryant Just searched the entire solution (I'm now the only one working on this app) and found nobody anywhere is going to sleep on any of the threads. Should each and every thread sleep ?  Not knowing or predicting the timing, I'm currently too scared to put the Serial Port background handler to sleep. I could probably put all the other threads to sleep for small increments of time; I'm wondering, since I'm going to get 20 channels of 64 samples of data, should I let each one sleep for 16 miliseconds ? How do I calculate the number ?

Comment: @User.1, did diabling vshost.exe not solve the problem?

Comment: @Dhawalk, I wish it had, but no, it did not. In fact, it injected a new/previous problem; i.e., semaphore timeout on the serial port when I tried to connect. I am experimenting with various sleeping times on various threads at this moment. I'm wondering, can I use a timer on one thread, get that value, and use it to sleep long enough for the other threads to execute uninterrupted ?

Comment: @User.1 Stop burning cpu time updating draw regions where nothing has changed.

Comment: @asawyer Good call ! Supposedly, I get 20 new data points (one point, twenty channels) every x-amount of time; whatever it is. From that, I'm supposing (wrongly ? correctly ?) that each hit from the Serial port guarantees a new draw region; i.e., guarantees that all 20 channels will keep changing all the time. I'll examine your idea a little more.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try disabling Visual studio hosting process from project properties. It's in Project properties --> Debug --> Enable Debuggers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here I think. The first, as others have mentioned is that your drawing threads are essentially infinite loops, and it appears that you're pausing for data by "busy waiting" which will use 100% CPU time of a single core per thread. Multiply that by the 20 threads you're using and you're giving the system enough work to fully occupy 20 CPU cores, far more than your system has, so it's starving other threads on the system, slowing the machine to a crawl.

I order for this to be responsive, you need to reimplement the pausing for data points using some sort of wait mechanism. Thread.Sleep is one such means, but it's likely to lead to jitter in your drawing. Instead, some kind of blocking queue e.g. BlockingCollection, which will allow your consumer threads to wait (without using CPU time) when there's no data available, rather than busy-waiting as your current implementation does.

The other issue is that drawing should always occur in the main thread, and having background threads doing drawing activities is likely to cause other problems.

Comment: Yikes, I have 4 or 5 other threads to boot ! The one thread which I am completely afraid to alter is the Serial Port background receiver; we absolutely positively gotta get the data. Can't miss a bit; that sort of thing. Could you (or anyone) give me an idea about the implications of using Thread.Sleep(NNN) with NNN set to either -1, 0, 1, or some larger positive integer.

Comment: Second question, could I put a timer into one of the drawing threads (probably the first) and calculate/estimate/whatever the amount of time that that thread took to draw that one set of lines (it will be 64 connected points) and set an external value, then multiply by 19, and let the other threads do their work, and let each one of those other threads do something like Thread.Sleep(N*18) for the next one, and Thread.Sleep(N*17) for the next and Thread.Sleep(N*16) for the next.... blah blah blah. So that the last thread just executes while the previous 19 are sleeping ??? Smart ? Stupid ?

Comment: @User.1 if you really want only one thread to be working at a time with the remainder all sleeping, why use threads at all? Just do all 20 consecutively on the same thread. Sleeps aren't the way to achieve this since you get no guarantee that it will sleep for exactly the duration specified (it should be close, but not necessarily exact) as a result, over time the threads will desynchronise.

Comment: Nice idea. This is collaborative; i.e., I'm the guy doing the communications and coordination, but my graphing skills are currently developing; a lot, real fast, but whatever. I'll ask about that. Yes, I like your ideas a lot. Not sure if I can do that.

Comment: @User.1 Also forgot to mention in my answer originally (now edited) that drawing on threads other than the main thread is generally a bad idea and likely to lead to other issues.

Comment: I welcome your ideas about what suggestions I might make to my local graphing guru. I'm pretty confident in the guru's capability, so I'm pretty certain that he had a good reason for putting the graphing routines in 20 threads. I'll ask him how much work it would be to put the thing into a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

Like mr Dhawalk said step by step :

1. In the 'solution explorer' right click on 'your project name'
2. Choose 'project properties' .
3. From the 'project properties' window select 'debug' options .
4. If 'enable the visual studio hosting process' checked : uncheck it .

See the illustration below:

[image]